# C program. Call a function that prints a string

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

Is there a way to make a function that stores a string, and then call that function in int main() that displays it on the screen? I have been searching a lot and haven't found a clear example. Here is my code. I would like to be able to call it without using the if statement

```
#include <stdio.h>


 /* function declaration */
  int StrPrint(char *str);
  /* main() function */
  int main()
     {
        char str[] = "The string i am returning n";
        int (*ptr)(char *str);

        ptr = StrPrint;
        if (!(*ptr)(str))
               printf("Done!\n");
            return 0;
     }
 /* function definition */
    int StrPrint(char *str)
        {
            printf("%s\n", str);
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have made a function to store a string but when i call it in the main it gives me an error.

Comment: Edit your post and include your code.

Comment: Does this code throws error? If so what is the error? The code looks good

Comment: No, it doesnt throw an error, i was just wondering if there was a way to use it without a pointer. With just a simple call to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by you if you don't like to use pointers it can be done as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

      int StrPrint(char s[])
        {
            printf("%s\n", s);
            return 0;
        }
  int main()
     {
        char str[] = "The string i am returning n";

        if (!StrPrint(str))
               printf("Done!\n");
            return 0;
     }
```

Comment: How would i use the function without the if statement?

Comment: The purpose of `if` is to print `Done` if it is not required just call the function and be done with it. Like `StrPrint(str)`

Comment: Thanks, its all very clear now, not sure why I didn't see that before, eeei, it's been a long week.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is far more complicated than the simple task you're trying to accomplish.

Why not something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void StrPrint(char* str);

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "The string i am returning n";
    StrPrint(str);
    return 0;
}

void StrPrint(char* str)
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

This conflicts slightly with your requirement, in that the function doesn't store a string it just prints out the string passed to it as an argument. But according to the code you posted, this looks like what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: That was the whole point of my question. Looking for a simpler way. thank you for the direction.

Comment: Only if you upvote my question, I have a rep to  maintain too